# Android windowManger remove flags

Tags: android

I have a `WindowManger` in a Service and I add some flags:

```
params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;

    params.y = 0; //topPadding
    params.x = 0;
    windowManager.updateViewLayout(view, params);
```

How can I remove `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE` later in another part?

Comment: From this code?  Just remove the name of the flag you don't want and the | after it.

Comment: @GuilhermeP yes remove it later in another part

Comment: @GabeSechan you mean how can i remove it from code ?

Comment: @medo I updated the question.. Now, I believe it is clearer

Comment: @GuilhermeP yes you are right

Answer (score 10):

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```

Answer (score 9):

Ok, to do it programatically later

```
   layoutParams.flags = layourParams.flags & ~flag_you_don't_want;
```

This will turn off only the bit you want off.  Then request a new layout to have the changes reflected on screen.

This technique is called "ANDing out" the bit.

Comment: what is it `layoutParams` ?

Comment: `params.flags = params.flags & ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE;` its dosen't removed

Comment: `params.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE;
        windowManager.updateViewLayout(view, params);`

_its work now_